# What is a technical value?

Tags: data, technicals, column-oriented

I'm trying to get my head around the following Kaggle competition:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/two-sigma-financial-modeling/data

The data is a frame made up of various columns, with a tuple structure as follows:

```
time,id,derived0,derived1,...,derivedn,fundemental0,fundemental1,...,fundementalm,technical0,technical1,....,technicalk
```

There are 3 types of value columns that represent:

1. Fundamental values
2. Derived values
3. Technical values

***Fundamental values*** are raw values say the stock price or temperature at time T

***Derived values*** are 'derived' from a combination of fundamental values perhaps?

eg:

```
time @ t_i derived[1] = fundamental[0] - fundamental[3] / fundamental[2]
```

But what is definition of ***technical value***?

What is an example technical value in terms of others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In conventional parlance, fundamental values would refer to data about the stock's financials, i.e. the data contained in the financial statements. Examples could be the cash flow, assets, liabilities and so on. Technical values would refer to data obtained from the price history of the stock, for example a 50 day moving average of the price, or the resistance level among other things. My guess is that derived values would be a function of technical and fundamental values here. Note that the competition mentioned might not adhere to these conventions.

Comment: so what you're saying is that technical values are generally linear composites, like EMAs, bollingers, etc of fundamentals and derived values.

Comment: @JuliaSterbs Technical values are a function of the price history generally, usually they do not incorporate fundamental information.